# Python - (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')

Tags: python, mysql

I'm familiar with this error, hence I increased the `interactive_timeout` and `wait_timeout` to X seconds. Hence whenever MySQL is idle for over X seconds, it reconnects(as per my code).

Following is the code.

```
from filename import getconnection, DButil

CONNECTION = getconnection()

def user():
    try:
        global CONNECTION
        if CONNECTION is None:
            CONNECTION = getconnection()
    except Exception,e:
        print e


    dbutil = DButil(CONNECTION)

    try:
        dbutil.data_exist(loginfo)
    except Exception,e:
        print e
```

**filename.py**

```
CONNECTION = None

def getconnection(recreate=True, db_name='db_name'):
    ''' Get a connection, if not available, make it '''
    global CONNECTION
    if recreate or CONNECTION is None:
        if db_name == 'db_name':
            CONNECTION = makeconnection()
    return CONNECTION



class DButil(object):
    '''Low level utiliity arrond db '''
    def __init__(self, _connection):
        self.connection = _connection


    def data_exist(self,data_exist_query):
        with self.connection:
            print self.connection # <_mysql.connection open to '127.0.0.1' at 1a587b0>
            cur = self.connection.cursor()
            print cur # <MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object at 0x1a22710> cur
            cur.execute(data_exist_query)
            rows = cur.fetchall()
            print rows #  (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
            if len(rows) >= 1 :
                return True
            else :
                return False
```

What I'm getting is that the connection is being made and isopen but when I do `rows = cur.fetchall()` it throws `(2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')`. Why's such behaviour??

When I reconnect, ie do `uwsgi reload` , it works fine sice the MySQL connection is again being established. Since, I also created the connection again when the server was idle for over X seconds, still it throws the error. WHY?

Comment: Totally OT but your try/except clauses are worth than useless...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers -  I'm more concerned for the error. :)